# Annotate: Pass parameter to Subquery

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a queryset as follow:

```
result = model_a.union(model_b)
```

The `result` have these fields:

```
 (`user`, `date`)
```

Is it possible pass `date` field to a `Subquery` as follow?

```
result.annotate(running_amount = Subquery(
                                  Model_C.objects.filter( 
                                                  Q(model_c__date__lt=('date') # <--- Pass date here
                                                    )
                                                 .aggregate(Sum('amount'), 0))['amount'] )
                                  output_field=IntegerField()
                                  ))
```

According to the above implementation, the following error occurs:

> ...
> raise FieldError('Related Field got invalid lookup:
> {}'.format(lookup_name)) django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Related
> Field got invalid lookup: date_lt

‍‍‍‍
**Questions:**

1. Is it possible to pass the fields from the ‍‍‍`result‍‍` to
   `Subquery`  in order to filtering?
2. Is there another way?

Comment: are you just expect one result from result query or list(queryset)??

Comment: can you post your models here???

Comment: @MohamedBeltagy list queryset.

Comment: I don't think this is possible.  For something like this I use a third party package which implements common table expressions in django.  See django-cte: https://github.com/dimagi/django-cte.  Django ORM is no use when you want to use a table as a temporary result for another sql query.  I think there are working on enhancing the ORM so that you can use subqueries inside the FROM clause of a sql expression.

Comment: Do you mean to say the queryset `result` has a field `date` that you want to refer in the inner query? See the documentation on [OuterRef](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.OuterRef). Also `annotate` is not supported after a `union`...

Comment: If annotate is not supported you are stuffed without a third party package like the one I mentioned.